# Inspecting variables using node's built-in debugger?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I am trying to use the node debugger.
I am running `node debug server` to run my server. Then I have:

```
...
var Workspace = mongoose.model('Workspace');
debugger;
```

At this point, as expected, when I run this code the debugger pops up.
However, I would expect it to have all of the current variables set, like it happens in Chrome's own debugger.

But:

```
break in hotplate/node_modules/bd/lib/bd.js:133
132 
133   debugger;
134 
135   // Delete the ID and the version since there's no point,
debug> Workspace
ReferenceError: Workspace is not defined
```

So... how do I *actually* inspect the current variables?

Bonus question: is there ANY way to use Chrome's developers tools (CTRL-J) so that it connects to the node and works that way? (I am aware of node-inspector, but it's very outdated and...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the bonus question has changed in 2018.

Run `node inspect foo.js`.

Visit `chrome://inspect` and in the list of devices you should see an entry that says `Target (<process.version>)` with an accompanying inspect link.

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the answer to the question? How do you inspect variables?

Answer (score 88):

Use `repl` command ( see third example in [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) )

```
break in hotplate/node_modules/bd/lib/bd.js:133
132 
133   debugger;
134 
135   // Delete the ID and the version since there's no point,
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> Workspace
```

Update: bonus question - https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent

Comment: What about the bonus question? :D

Comment: not sure if there is readily available solution other then node-inspector but you could try to use chrome developer tools remote debugger - https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: any idea how to get it to output the full variable instead of truncating it?

Comment: is that a string? V8 debugger agent only returns first 80 chars of a string, so you have to select other part ( `mystring.slice(123)` - substring starting from index 123 ) or ask debuggee to output it ( `console.log(mystring)` )

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec` to inspect variables. It's much faster and you don't have to switch to a REPL.

```
break in hotplate/node_modules/bd/lib/bd.js:133
132 
133   debugger;
134 
135   // Delete the ID and the version since there's no point,
debug> exec workspace
```