# How do I use node debug cli with Jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, node-debugger, babel-jest

How can I just use the simple node cli/repl debugger with Jest?

The [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/troubleshooting.html) uses [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), but it is outdated/deprecated as of Node 6.3. I tried the recommended command anyway on Node 7.7.4:

```
node --debug-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --no-cache [your_test_file]
```

But this simply hangs on the following (assumedly waiting on node-inspector):

`(node:13452) DeprecationWarning: node --debug is deprecated. Please use node --inspect instead. Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858`

I added `--inspect` as specified by the warning, but even then execution doesn't stop on my `debugger` statement in Chrome DevTools.

This seems overly complicated for a very simple use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From node v8.4 the `debugger` keyword within the code is fixed for VM context. Refer [this git comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1652#issuecomment-322834017).

1.**Type *debugger* keyword in your Jest code**:

```
describe('Testcase definition', () => {
   it('should be defined with subobjects', () => {
     debugger; // <-- This keyword breaks on Chrome inspect
     expect(true).toBe(true);
   });
});
```

2. **Command to Run:**

   > node --inspect-brk --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/jest -i tests/mytest.test.js
3. **Now open** [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices) on Chrome. Voila!

Answer (score 4):

I found the following command works:

`node debug ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --no-cache [your_test_file]`

...but with some quirky behavior. When the debugger first stops you will see:

```
break in node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js:10
  8  */
  9
>10 'use strict';
 11
 12 require('jest-cli/bin/jest');
debug>
```

Apparently Jest always injects this breakpoint so that you have time to open Chrome DevTools (irrelevant in our case since we're only going to use cli/repl).

Continue past this breakpoint with `c`, and after a short time (without any indication of course that things are progressing along) you should see your breakpoint:

```
break in webpack/assets/react/components/presentation/Feed/Comments/Comment/commentSpec.jsx:12
 10     var wrapper = (0, _enzyme.shallow)(_react2.default.createElement(_comment2.default, { loading: true }));
 11
>12     debugger;
 13     expect(wrapper.find(_button2.default)).to.have.length(1);
 14   });
 debug>
```

The last weird thing is you need to type repl to inspect objects as described in [Node Debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) and [Inspecting variables using node's built-in debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926143/inspecting-variables-using-nodes-built-in-debugger/13926782#13926782)

The combination of all these steps was not immediately obvious to me while reading the documentation, so I hope this answer helps someone get over the hurdle faster.